# MongoDB giving weird Connection Error

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having a problem with connecting to MongoDB with PHP. 
This is my code:

```
<?php
$server = new Mongo('localhost:27017'); 
$db = $server->sampleDB;
$coll = $db->sample;
?>
```

This produces the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'localhost:27017: couldn't get host info for localhost' in /var/www/example/index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/example/index.php(2): Mongo->__construct('localhost:27017') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/wexample/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Can you connect from the mongodb shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem; 
Turns out for some reason Mongo was only listening on `127.0.0.1`, not `localhost`.

So, using `$server = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");`, instead of `$server = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017");` fixed the problem :)

Thanks for your help guys, 
James

Comment: that's actually kinda wrong terminology seeing as 127.0.0.7 is still localhost but just a different method of accessing it... :P

Comment: As strange as weird... Thanks for sharing answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoconnectionexception.php)

> couldn't get host info for [server]
>
> This indicated that DNS could not
> resolve the server address you gave.
> This could easily be caused by a typo,
> for example, "server" instead of
> "$server".

As well, you might want to read the [Connecting part of the MongoDB section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php) in PHP doc

**EDIT**

Have you tried this ?:

```
$server = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Comment: I've already read that, I know that that's the problem, but I don't know how to fix it :-/ thanks

Comment: What is your OS ? is any kind of firewall enabled ?... :-/

Comment: Did you try 1.1.1.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Thanks @Frosty Z / @jared, fixed the problem and posted solution below :)