# Mongodb connectivity error

Tags: php, mongodb

```
<?php
/**
 * Connects to MongoDB server.
 * Stops code execution on`enter code here` connection error.
 *
 * You do not need to use this file, just any place to globally assign a MongoDB instance to $db.
 *
 * Define constants in your config or here
 */

 define('MDB_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('MDB_PASSWORD', 'asd');
 define('MDB_HOST', 'localhost:80');
 define('MDB_NAME', 'abc');


if (!class_exists('Mongo')) {
    die("Mongo class not existing. Did you install the PHP MongoDB extension?");
}

try {
    $conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://".MDB_USERNAME.":".MDB_PASSWORD."@".MDB_HOST."/".MDB_NAME);
    $conn->authenticate('root','gynadfehurbo');
    $db = $conn->selectDB(MDB_NAME);
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage()); // In production you might want to turn this off.
}
```

Mongodb connectivity problem.

while am trying to connect mongodb with php got authentication problem ..By giving **port** the above error is replaced as connection refused .then i changed the port that error has been replaced as

> Failed to connect to: localhost:80: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 60.000000 seconds

Comment: What happens when you use the default port(27017)]? Also did you see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425089/mongodb-giving-weird-connection-error?rq=1

Comment: i got an error "connection refused" when i use the default port 27017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $server = "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname";   // Connecting to server 
$c = new MongoClient($server ); 

  if($c->connected)

        echo "Connected successfully";

 else

         echo "Connection failed";
```